# $ \sum_{1 \le k,j \le n}a_kb_j$ is maximum when $k=j$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem: If $a_r >a_{r+1}>0$ and $b_r >b_{r+1}>0$ for $1 \le r \le n-1$ prove that:

$\displaystyle \sum_\limits{1 \le k,j \le n}a_kb_j$ is maximum when $k=j$.

I already know a proof of this by induction, so I'm looking for other methods.

Comment: its called chebyshev inequality.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maximal/maximum with respect to what and what does 'when $k=j$' mean? It could be helpful to rephrase it.